# Converting regex query to English keyword query

Tags: java, regex, reflection, tree

I am trying to convert a regex query to keyword query, such that the keyword query gives me a superset of the regex query. For example

- "host.*" can convert to "host*"
- "host ((?10\.6\.2*)) ChuckN*" can convert to "host *", "10 6 *", "Chuck*"
- "host.* registered.+" can convert to "host*", "registered*"
- "10\.64\.2*" can convert to "10 64 *"

For this I am looking for a regex tree whose leaf elements can be combined to get the keyword query. I am trying to access the data structure inside pattern class in java used to store the regex. Please let me know how this could be done or if there is some other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println(
      (     "host."
        + "\nhost ((?10\\.6\\.2*)) ChuckN*"
        + "\nhost.* registered.+" 
        + "\n10\\.64\\.2*"
      )
        .replaceAll("(.?\\*)", "*")
        .replaceAll("\\.\\+", "*")
        .replaceAll("\\\\.", " ")
        .replaceAll("(\\.?[^A-Za-z0-9 \\*\\n])", "")
    );
```

output

```
host
host 10 6 * Chuck*
host* registered*
10 64 *
```

**Edit** : *Last* replaceAll *line corrected.*
You may have to complete the sString in last *.replaceAll("sString", "")*.